# Where I can put my jar ? Ear with Jboss 5.1

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss5.x, ear

I don't know how to structure my ear file in my context.

Here is my actual structure:

```
ear
--lib
--war1
--war2
--warA
--warB
```

In ear/lib, I have all common jars between wars. Everything works fine but my ear is heavy.

In fact, war1 and war2 share some jars. WarA and warB too.

I don't put these jars in ear/lib because warA/B don't use everything and war1/2 too.

Today, war1/2 come with every jars, so some jars are in double.

I would like to have something like this:

```
ear
--lib (common jars)
--war1
--war2
--something who comes with common jars for war1/2
--warA
--warB
--something who comes with common jars for warA/B
```

Like this, war1 and war2 will be lighter. Same thing for warA and war B.

Do you know if I can do that and what kind of archive I can use to do that ? jar, war, sar ? I'm on Jboss 5.1

Thanks

Comment: Does it matter if all 4 wars get to see the all the classes in the ear? In other words do you just need the WARs to be isolated in their own domain and look for additional classes in the parent domain?

Comment: Today, war1/2 are isolated to warA/B and they are the parent domain (ear domain) in common.

Comment: FYI I wrote an article on my blog (french language) on this interesting problem about Jboss classLoader => http://blog-dev.net/technique/serveurs/bug-classcastexception-et-classloader-jboss/001758

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the PROBLEM is: you've an ear with two sets of wars: each set use a different version of the same library (so the version used by the first set must be isolated from the second, and viceversa), and you don't want to have to place the same library several times in different places of the ear. A part of these libraries, you may have other libraries shared by all the modules.

Possible SOLUTION:
You could add a new war for each of the sets, those will just contain the libraries shared by the rest of wars in the same set. Then,to make it work without classloading problems you should isolate each set by placing a jboss-classloading.xml conveniently configured in each of the wars WEB-INF directory, and in the META-INF/jboss-classloading.xml of the ear which keeps the wars.

So the structure would be something like:

```
yourapp.ear
    |
    |--lib
    |    |- place here the libraries shared by all the wars in the ear
    |
    |--META-INF
    |     |
    |     |-jboss-classloading.xml
    |
    |--war1SetA.war
    |     |
    |     |-WEB-INF
    |           |- jboss-classloading.xml    
    |           |
    |           |- classes
    |      
    |     
    |--war2SetA.war
    |     |
    |     |-WEB-INF
    |           |- jboss-classloading.xml    
    |           |
    |           |- classes
    |      
    |      
    |--libsSetA.war
    |     |
    |     |-WEB-INF
    |           |- jboss-classloading.xml    
    |           |
    |           |- lib
    |                |-Place here the libraries used by wars of setA
    |       
    |--war1SetB.war
    |     |
    |     |-WEB-INF
    |           |- jboss-classloading.xml    
    |           |
    |           |- classes
    |     
    |--war2SetB.war
    |     |
    |     |-WEB-INF
    |           |- jboss-classloading.xml    
    |           |
    |           |- classes
    |     
    |--libsSetB.war
          |
          |-WEB-INF
                |- jboss-classloading.xml    
                |
                |- lib
                     |-Place here the libraries used by wars of setB
```

The wars named libsSet* are used just to keep the libraries used by the wars of the same set.

The jboss-classloading.xml of the wars in set A should be similar to:

```
<classloading xmlns="urn:jboss:classloading:1.0"
    domain="SetA"
    export-all="NON_EMPTY"
    import-all="true"
    parent-domain="yourapp.ear"
    parent-first="false">
</classloading>
```

And for wars in set B, it should be:

```
<classloading xmlns="urn:jboss:classloading:1.0"
    domain="SetB"
    export-all="NON_EMPTY"
    import-all="true"
    parent-domain="yourapp.ear"
    parent-first="false">
</classloading>
```

IMPORTANT: the domain attribute must be the same for all the wars in the same set.

And finally the META-INF/jboss-classloading.xml in the ear file should be:

```
<classloading xmlns="urn:jboss:classloading:1.0"
   domain="yourapp.ear"
   export-all="NON_EMPTY"
   import-all="true"
   parent-first="false">
</classloading>
```

Another possible solution, similar to this one, would be placing the shared libraries of each set in one of the wars of the set, this way you wouldn't need a war just for libraries.

Comment: I have already isolated my wars with this jboss-classloading.xml and it's work fine. I didn't think I can do a war without context. I think I will use this solution. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @ToniS.Magraner is there any performance issue, if we load all jar's separately from wars?(By placing all jar separately in wars)

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood it correctly you don't have any problems of library versions and isolation, so independently of if a library is used by all the war archives or not, you can place them all inside the ear's lib directory (you could even consider placing the libraries in the jboss instance lib directory, and removing them from the ear/wars!). This way the ear file will have the smallest size possible.

Don't worry about the memory used, the JBoss classloader will just load once the libraries, so they will be shared by all the wars that need them (another case would be if you need a different version of the same library for each war).

On the other hand, if any of the libraries is just used by one of the war file, it will also be optimal if you place the library inside this war's lib directory.

So your first approach is right, I don't think you need to change it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't place jars in server/lib because the production team doesn't want manage it. I provide the ear at this team and I don't have the hand on the machine. I know Jboss loads only once the librairie. I just would like reduce the size of ear and to know if it's possible to do what I think. My first approach works fine but it's not "ideal" to have twice the same jar.

Comment: Then I've not understood your first approach. With the first approach you would only have to place the jars in one place: the ear's lib directory (so you don't need to place it in the wars, so you can remove them from here).

Comment: Ok, I think I misspoke. In the ear/lib, I have common jars for all war(1/2/A/B). But war 1/2 share some jars not compatible with warA/B which share jars too. war1/2 are isolated together in one classloader which have for parent the ear domain. warA/B are isolated together too with the ear domain for parent domain. Everythings works like this, it's ok but I would like one another archive (not in ear/lib because it's not common between every wars) which contains common jars for war1/2 (so, I can remove these jars from war1/2). I hope it's clearer like this :)

Comment: Ok, if there are conflicts between libraries the problem is more complex. At the moment I'm thinking about two possible solutions: The first one consists of mixing the wars 1-2 in just one single war and A-B in another single war? Another approach would be separate your main application ear in two or three ears: one for wars A-B, another for wars 1-2 (and maybe a third one for the shared libraries).

Comment: I can't merge war1/2 together because of jsf and memory. Three ears is a good approach but I insist, is it possible to have another archive inside ear to do that ?